# Outlook if mso conditions

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office, html-email

I wonder is it possible to specify more than one exact versions of Outlook in one `if mso` condition? Like

```
//pseudo
if mso9 OR mso10 OR mso11
apply these styles
end if
```

If it is, please can someone give a link to the syntax explanation?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this approach does work.

```
<!--[if (mso 9)|(mso 10)|(mso 11)]>
```

Here is a link: https://litmus.com/community/code/396-conditional-code-for-outlook

Comment: you can also just have `<!--[if mso]>`  as well to affect all versions